# In February, what does Oktober d.J. mean?

Tags: meaning, time, abbreviation

I saw the following phrase in an article, written in this year:

> Oktober d.J.

Because the full form of d.J. is *dieses Jahres*, would that mean October 2016?

If I wanted to mean October 2015, can I write v.J. for voriges Jahres?

Comment: More context, please. Could you give the source, for example?

Comment: @Stephie Unfortunately not. I wanted to use the phrase again, in a similiar way, then I thought of that what was written in the article, but I can't find the source or context anymore. However, the answer I accepted answers all my questions, and it probably would also answer the questions of future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. v.J = vorigen Jahres - see the usual abbreviations from the following list (from Duden):

- dieses (besser nicht diesen) Jahres (Abkürzung d. J.)
- im Jahr[e] (Abkürzung i. J.)
- laufenden Jahres (Abkürzung lfd. oder l. J.)
- künftigen Jahres (Abkürzung k. J.)
- nächsten Jahres (Abkürzung n. J.)
- vorigen Jahres (Abkürzung v. J.)

But anyway I would prefer Okt. 2015 instead because it will not expire next year :)

Comment: Thank you, but does Oktober d.J. mean Okober 2015 or Oktober 2016, assuming it is 2016?

Comment: If you say it in 2016 Oktober d. J means Okt. 2016. Oktober v. J. means Okt. 2015.

Comment: könnte **l. J.** nicht auch _letzten Jahres_ bedeuten?

Comment: könnte man in der Tat mißverstehen. Vielleicht sollte man es besser ausschreiben. Ich habe die Abkürzungen aus dem Duden kopiert.

Answer (score 7):

This is - as so often - a matter of *context*.

If the author writes about current events, yes, it could mean October 2016.

However, if the article describes something happening in, say, 1961, d.J. would consequently mean October 1961, even if the article is published 2016.

Unfortunately the snippet you give does not allow a definitive answer.

Comment: And part of this is that _d. J._ can also stand for _des Jahres_ instead of _dieses Jahres_.

Comment: If the author is wise enough, he'd say "j. J." for "jenes Jahres" ;)